# Find out if CsElement is a static field? (StyleCop custom rule)

Tags: c#, code-analysis, stylecop

How do I query a CsElement object to see if the element is a static field?

I'm building a pair of m_ and s_ prefix rules for member fields and static fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely should take a look at [StyleCop+](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/). It already contains all naming rules you're trying to create.

Moreover, it's open-source. So you can find there many examples of different code analysis cases (finding all static fields, member fields, etc.)

Comment: That's completely brilliant! Thank you! :)