# How can I set up in StyleCop rules that all private fields must begin with underscore?

Tags: .net, stylecop

How can I set up in StyleCop rules that all private fields must begin with underscore `_`?

Comment: Add also rule that every function should contain at least one goto statement:)

Comment: [This](http://scottwhite.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-custom-stylecop-rules-in-c.html) might be useful for you with a few minor changes.

Answer (score 4):

You could take a look at [StyleCop+](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/) with its flexible naming rules. It is open-source, so you could also use it for writing your own custom rules.

P.S. A similar question: [Find out if CsElement is a static field? (StyleCop custom rule)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037695/find-out-if-cselement-is-a-static-field-stylecop-custom-rule/6040310)

Comment: That link doesn't work and I can't turn up much -- is StyleCop+ no more?

Answer (score 4):

`SX1309FieldNamesMustBeginWithUnderscore` StyleCop rule gets the job done.
https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SX1309.md

This rule can be configured with action `error` in ruleset file as below to achieve the desired objective.

```
 <Rules AnalyzerId="StyleCop.Analyzers" RuleNamespace="StyleCop.Analyzers">
       <Rule Id="SX1309" Action="Error" />
 </Rules>
```